# Can I leave Australia and re enter on a visitor visa from South Africa?

Tags: visas

I am from South Africa. I have a three month visitor visa for Australia. I had to come back to South Africa after one month. I plan to go back so can I re enter Australia on the same visa that has not yet expired?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your visa. Look at your visa grant notice, if you can enter multiple times there will be something like "Your visa allows you multiple entries to Australia until..."